# Why does Flask/Flask-Restful require me to access the request form to function properly?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm creating a Rest API using Flask (2.0.1), Flask-Restful (0.3.9), and Python 3.9, and ran into an interesting issue/bug(?).

I was able to replicate this using the basic Flask Rest API code below

**my_api.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
rest_api = Api(app)


@rest_api.resource('/my/route')
class GetData(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        return jsonify({'hello': 'world'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=12345)
```

**my_requests.py**

```
import requests
url = r'http://127.0.0.1:12345/my/route'
rsp = requests.get(url)
print(rsp.json())
```

When I run the code above, `my_requests.py` returns the expected output. I get `{'hello': 'world'}` as my response

The issue I am running into is when I pass in form data into the get request to pull back data based on different parameters:

```
import requests
url = r'http://127.0.0.1:12345/my/route'
rsp = requests.get(url, data={'my': 'data'})
```

By adding in `data`, I get the following error:

> ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)

After much troubleshooting, I figured out that my Rest API requires me to access the form data by calling `request.form`, as such

```
def get():
    data = request.form
    return jsonify({'hello': 'world'})
```

By calling `request.form`, only then does `my_requests.py` returns the expected output like before.

So my question is why does flask/flask-restful require me to access `request.form` to perform properly when passing in data? I won't always being accessing the data that's being passed in, so it seems weird that it would be designed this why

Comment: What is the error message returned by your Flask console?

Comment: @Szabolcs There are no errors in my Flask console. The only error I get is the one I posted here

Comment: i just tried your example but on my side it also works if i pass in some data in the request. So i do not had to use the `request.form` call

Comment: Why do you use the `@staticmethod` decorator? Could that be the cause?

Comment: @MatteoPasini Doesn't seem to be the case. The error occurs with or without `staticmethod` (added it as apart of my troubleshooting), and that is is just the version that ended up in the SO post